# Evaluating $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^{2n-1}}$

Tags: summation, geometric-series

> What is the summation of this geometric series?$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^{2n-1}}$$

My main confusion is the difference between starting at n=1 versus starting at $n=0$. When you start at $n=1$ I assume that the way that you can apply the geometric sum rule is if the exponent is $n-1(x^{n-1})$. But when you start at n=0 if the exponent is just $n (x^n)$ you can apply it there as well. This summation starts at n=1 so how can I turn it into $x^{n-1}$ so that I can use the geometric sum rule.

Comment: so add the zero term, apply the formula, and then subtract the zero term from the result.

Comment: Use the formula $\frac{a}{1 - r}$, where $a$ is the first term and $r$ is the common ratio. If the series starts at $n = 0$, then find $a$ by substituting $n = 0$ into the formula. If the series starts at $n = 1$, then find $a$ by subbing $n = 1$ instead.

Comment: Alt. hint: $\,\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^{2n-1}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2 \,\cdot\, 2^{2(n-1)}}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2^{2n}}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{4^n}\,$.

Comment: More generally,$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)=\sum_{m=0}^\infty f(m+1).$$

Answer (score 1):

We have that
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{2n-1}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{2^{2n}}=2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4^n}=2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{4})^n$
We want our series to begin from $n=0$ so we add and substract $(\frac{1}{4})^0=1$, hence
$2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{4})^n=2[(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{4})^n)-1]=2(\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{4}}-1)=2(\frac{4}{3}-1)=\frac{2}{3}.$
We have that $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{4})^n=\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{4}}$$
because this is a geometric series.